# R Shiny reactive function in betareg() object

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am trying to create an app for beta regression. If the dependent variable is not defined on 0 and 1, the dependent variable will be transformed into (0,1) interval.

The simple code is given below. However, I take the following error "invalid model formula in ExtractVars".

Thank you in advance for your answers.

```
    newy=reactive({
        req(data(),input$yvar)
        y <- as.numeric(data()[[as.name(input$yvar)]])
        yy=(y-min(y))/(max(y)-min(y))
        return(yy)
    })
        
    lmModel <- reactive({
        req(data(),input$xvar,input$yvar,newy())

        if(input$yes==TRUE){
            model <- betareg(reformulate(input$xvar,response=newy(),data=data()), na.action=na.exclude)
            return(model)
            
        }else{
            model <- betareg(reformulate(input$xvar,response=input$yvar), data = data(), na.action=na.exclude)
            return(model)
        }
        
    })
```

Comment: can we have a [mcve] please ???

Comment: In one call you have `reformulate(input$xvar,response=newy(),data=data())`, and in another call you have `reformulate(input$xvar,response=input$yvar), data = data()`.  Make sure that your `)` is in the right place.